# tSQL - Increment value based on COUNT function

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

Probably a dumb question, but sometimes things that seem impossible turn out to be easy for more experienced people.

I have a table with 41 columns and about 20000 records, and I've been given a requirement to eliminate duplicates based on a combination of 16 fields that must be unique. I can use the COUNT function to find records with two or more instances of identical records based on those fields.

My question is, does SQL have the capability to change the value of a field if the count is greater than 1? I've noodled around with making a subquery, but every solution I can think of will change both duplicates to the same new value - I can't figure out how to just change one of the duplicates.

I may be barking up the wrong tree, but I just thought I'd ask. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you want to remove or modify duplicates?

Comment: Modify - there is a field called 'Replicate' that I'm supposed to use to make the records unique by changing the replicates to 1, 2, 3...

Comment: Yes you can do this. Is it SQL Server?

Comment: I think your going to need a subquery then to isolate the duplicates and perform the modification

Comment: Yes. SQL Server. And Pesudo, yes, but I can't envision what that would look like.

Comment: Is replicates one of the 16 fields that is supposed to be unique?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to accomplish what you are asking along with row_number(). Basically you assign a rownumber within each partition defined by your 16 columns. Then set the replicate field to that rownumber. Note the logic is very basic in my example as we don't know much about your data.

```
;with cte
as 
(
  select *, 
    row_number() over(partition by col1, col2,... order by col1) as dupCount 
  from yourTable
)

update cte
set [replicate] = dupCount
```

Comment: Chao, looking at CTE now, need to educate myself quickly... thanks so much for this lead, let me try it.

Comment: @Stanton I'd recommend creating a copy of your table and trying the cte/update there if you aren't familiar. Don't want to run the wrong update on production data. Also before you run the update you can just do a `select * from cte` so you can get an idea of what it's doing.

Comment: Chao, this is going to take some more self-education. Need to gnaw on your solution for a while. Thanks again.